# Windows Server 2003: this computer is in use and has been locked - disable it

Tags: windows, screensaver, session

Windows Server 2003 will lock the screen after ten minutes of idle time.  In a production environment of course, this is NOT a problem.

Using Windows in a development environment, I don't need to protect anything from anyone.  I want to minimize my chances of carpal tunnel by avoiding the hassle of entering my password every time I want to see what's up on the Windows machine.

How can I stop the screen being locked after this idle time?

Comment: I debated that before posting, you are totally right, BUT this is related to my development work on a Coldfusion application. This answer is valuable to me as a developer :)

Comment: I need to wait 8 hours to answer my own question, but it's on the way in 8!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Solution**

Some or all of these things will prevent Server 2003 from locking the screen after idle time.

Goto Start > Run and type gpedit.msc

Once it comes up go to computer configuration go to:
Windows > Settings > local policies > security options

From there you will see the require Ctl-Alt-Del setting. Disable it.

Next find the one that says “Amount of idle time required before suspending session” and change it to its maximum value 99999.

**THIS ONE is the definite fixer:**

Control Panel -> Display -> tab: Screen Saver -> checkbox: On resume, password protect

**Un-check that**.

Dear Microsoft, thanks for putting that into "Display Properties > Screen Saver" instead some place named "Security Options."

Comment: To be fair, that options has existed on that screen for over 20 years, before Windows even knew what Security was.

Comment: Fair enough! I'm sure it would be equally annoying for long time windows users if they moved it too.

Comment: The “Amount of idle time required before suspending session” solved it for me and I was able to change it while in a remote desktop session.. thanks